# Store elements of vector into cells

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have a vector of numbers and I want to store the every four elements into a cell. So the first 4 elements will go into the first cell, the next four elements will go into the second cell and so on.

Is there a way to do this without using loops? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`mat2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) to do this

```
data = 1:16;
output = mat2cell(data, 1, (numel(data)/4) * ones(1,4))

%   output{1} =
%   
%      1   2   3   4
%   
%   output{2} =
%   
%      5   6   7   8
%   
%   output{3} =
%   
%       9   10   11   12
%   
%   output{4} =
%   
%      13   14   15   16
```

Personally I find the input format a little confusing. Another approach would be to reshape your matrix to have 4 rows and then use [`num2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html) to break each column into it's own cell.

```
data = 1:16;
output = num2cell(reshape(data, 4, []), 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I personally prefer the second method as it is easier to understand!